# Use the same sql Server table to do different updates, is there a way to do that?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

Im using Asp.net (VB.net), in my Database :

- have One table called (Trade), the same rows of this table are used from **3 different users**, These users can make different updates on this table, they should see the basic informations of the table (I mean by the Basic, before the table (trade) has been updated)
- The problem is here when the **first user** wants to modify the table's rows, the **second** and **third user** cannot see the basic information any more, and if they decide to change or update some data, the first will lose his updated rows..

The data will be overwritten every time the users make updates on the table.

What I want, is to know if there is a way to do like a copy, or an image of the table for the 3 users, and every user can update normally, without creating the same Table with the same rows 3 times??!

**Update**
My table structure is: Trade(trName, Carrier, POl, POD, Vgp, Qgp) There is no primary key..

Thank you..

Comment: Your problem can be solved by adding a `UserId` column to your table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to your problem could be two copies of the original table. Show the original table always to the user as the initial data. And in second table keep the updated data always. Now the trick comes here to maintain the log, for that you have to maintain the log table, this table will have all the fields of original table along with one additional column "UserId", this will have the ID of user who has changed the value. Now each time before updating the data, copy it in the log table. If this suits your need then post the fields of your table then we can workout on the table structures.

Comment: I think this solution can solve my Problem, I will Update my question and post my table fields..

Comment: Trade(trName, Carrier, POl, POD, Vgp, Qgp) - Original Table                     Trade_Updated(RowId(primaryKey),trName,Carrier, POl, POD,Vgp, Ogp) - Latest Data                                                                    ChangeLog(UserId, RowId, oldTrName,oldCarrier,oldPol,oldPOD,oldVgp,oldQgp) - Here the crux is to find the change, so you can add two more colums. FieldUpdated, NewValue. So for example, user has modified the POD value, so FieldUpdated column will have POD, and NewValue of POD will be in NewValue column.

Comment: Can you please explain this to me with queries, I mean at the beginning I will do for all users( select * from trade), and I will create table with the same columns as trade as well as RowId called trade_updated, and if the user wants to updates some rows, The querry will be (Insert into trade_updated values..) not (update) and (insert into  ChangeLog values..) with the rows_Id and User_Id .. Can you please give me the querries example ..?

Comment: am I right..? the queries should start like that ? can you Please explain how the queries should look like ?

Comment: Sorry @tollamie, I could not post it yeterday. Here are the queries (might need to check the syntax). Assuming you have copied the data in trade_updated.Now user has fired the query to update the record through your application. Before firing the query Update trade_updated(....). Run the query.. Insert into ChangeLog(userId,col1,col2,col3,...,Updated Column Name,new Value). Here assumption is that user will update only one value at a time.

Comment: And if I want to update more than one value at a time I should add to the table ChangeLog the other Updated Column Name and the new value, I mean I should add in ChangeLog table Two columns for every cloumn in trade_updated table ?

Comment: There we can have different approach: 1. Update one value at a time and create the change log for each change, i.e. values for col1 and col2 has been changed, so first row will have the col1 as Column name and value. Another row for col2 value. 2. Another approach could be comma separated values, i.e col1,col2 in column name and col1 value,col2 value. Here sequence matters so you need to be careful. 3. Third approach could be use of XML like <col1>NewValue</col1> <col2>NewValue</col2>

Comment: Ok I will try to use one of these approach, Thank you for your time